# Who were some famous Vietnam War Hawks and Doves?

Tags: united-states, vietnam-war, vietnam

Who were some famous people who opposed/supported the Vietnam War?

Comment: Jane Fonda, ""Hanoi Jane", comes to mind.

Comment: Wonderful.  Do you know anybody who was a war hawk?

Comment: This is something pretty much every US citizen alive at the time had an opinion on. Strong opinion by the end. So there needs to be a bit more specificity here. Exactly what kind of people are you looking for? Politicans only? Media types? People who were famous at the time? People who made an impact at the time?

Comment: @LarsTech how could I forget Jane Fonda, thanks.

Comment: Not a bad question, but needs more context regarding why it is being asked, and what you are looking for in an anawer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hawks**

[Robert S. McNamara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_S._McNamara) Secretary of Defense during the Kennedy, and Johnson administrations.

[Henry Kissinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kissinger) for his work prior to becoming National Security Advisor.

[Lyndon B. Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_B._Johnson) for his escalation of the war.

[John F. Kennedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy) for his involvement prior to the declaration of war.

**Doves**

[John Lennon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lennon) for his activism.

[Ron Dellums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Dellums) for his election as an anti-war activist, not to mention his war crimes exhibit.

[Tim L. Carter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Lee_Carter), Republican congressman from Kentucky who implored the US to withdraw troops, in 1967.

[Martin Luther King, Jr.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King) for his opposition.

[Jane Fonda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Fonda) for her activism.